# How do you get a meteor shot?

Tags: terraria

How do you get a meteor shot?

I want one but don't know how. Any chance There is a different and easier way to get to a floating island?

Comment: The reason this is getting downvoted is because this information is easily found.  We like to see effort when someone asks a question, and not even doing a google search beforehand means these types of questions get a very unwelcome reception.

Comment: Pluto, if you have a new question, you need to make a new post for that question. Don't modify an old question into something completely different. And about the voodoo demon question - they are rare. Sometimes you won't see one for 10+ minutes of playtime. Unless you think there's some different problem other than bad RNG, you might want to reconsider posting that question as well.

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry. I'm newer-ish here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can craft [meteor shot](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteor_Shot) with 70 regular bullets and one meteorite bar. Meteor shot bullets bounce exactly once, so shooting them upwards is a good way to find sky islands, since the bullet will come back down if it hits an island. The bullets can also pierce up to one enemy, but only if they haven't bounced already.

If you're looking for other methods of finding sky islands, take a look at [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/157772/145980) (and [my answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/297829/145980) (/shameless plug)).

Answer (score 1):

Meteor shot is a type of ammo you can craft for firearms in order to make 70 bullets you require 70 musket balls and 1 meteorite bar. These bullets are able to bounce off of hard surfaces making finding sky islands since you can either see the shot reflect back down or hear the sound of the bullet bouncing off walls.

Source: [Terraria Wiki Meteor Shot](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteor_Shot)